# Why do spaces in a file name cause IE to remove a file extension on file download?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, download, asp.net-mvc-5, file-extension

I am using [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) to create an Excel file from a CSV which works without issue. Unfortunately, the below code causes Internet Explorer 9, 10, and 11 to drop the `.xlsx` file extension, while Chrome and Firefox do not. If I remove the spaces from the file name the file extension works as expected in IE.

```cs
public FileStreamResult DetailsExcel(string id)
{
    string custName;
    var csv = this.GetCsvForCustomer(id, out custName);
    var fileName = String.Format("Report for {0} ({1:d-M-yyyy HH mm})",
        custName, DateTime.Now);

    MemoryStream stream;

    using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        var ws = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(fileName);
        ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromText(csv, this._excelTextFormat);
        stream = new MemoryStream(excelPackage.GetAsByteArray());
    }

    return File(stream,
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
        fileName + ".xlsx");
}
```

The two programmatic mechanisms that I have found that *somewhat* work are to wrap the file name in quotes or to UrlEncode the string. Each have issues:

```cs
String.Format("\"{0}\".xlsx", fileName)
// above renders: __Report for Customer (20-2-2014 11 04)__.xlsx

HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fileName + ".xlsx")
// above renders: Report+for+Customer+(20-2-2014+11+04).xlsx
```

Neither of the above are optimal. How do I include spaces in a file name without losing the file extension when a user is browsing with IE?

Comment: Looks like you got `__` instead of quotes : ). The whole name including filename and extension needs to be quoted.

Comment: @Teemu right which is better than the UrlEncode option, but still not awesome. :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to reproduce the behavior you describe in a similar application that I have. The only difference is that I'm not loading the byte array into a `MemoryStream` first, but just passing the byte array to `File`.

So try removing the `MemoryStream` from the equation. So the code would end up something like:

```
public ActionResult DetailsExcel(string id)
{
    byte[] stream;  // changed to byte array

    using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        var ws = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(fileName);
        ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromText(csv, this._excelTextFormat);
        stream = excelPackage.GetAsByteArray();  // removed MemoryStream
    }

    return File(stream,
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
        fileName + ".xlsx");
}
```

Comment: On mobile right now so haven't tested your fix out. In the meantime wanted to ask if your similar application is ASP.NET MVC 5?

Comment: @ahsteele My project is MVC4. But looking at the source code for ASP.NET MVC, [`FileContentResult`](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/FileContentResult.cs) and [`FileStreamResult`](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/FileStreamResult.cs) haven't changed since April 6, 2012. So they are the same in MVC4 and MVC5. Granted, something else in the stack could affect it, but I'm thinking it's the way IE handles the chunking that `FileStreamResult` uses.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing on the way home. Will definitely give it a whirl in the morning. Thank you for following up and I will let you know.

Comment: I'm working on the same code base as @ahsteele, and though ridding of the extraneous stream has cleaned things up I'm afraid it has had no affect on the presence of the file extension.